# Does Django expose a way to consume the next id in a sequence without creating an object?

Tags: django

I'm looking for a way to "reserve" the next id for a particular model without having to save an actual object.  I know that I could go to the underlying database directly to query the sequence like this **postgres specific** solution:

```
def get_next_id(model_class):
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute( "select nextval('%s_id_seq')" % \
                    model_class._meta.db_table)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    return row[0]
```

Detailed here: https://gist.github.com/kissgyorgy/6110380

What I'm hoping for is that there's some Django function which would abstract away the db layer for me.  Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

[The docs say:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys)

> There's no way to tell what the value of an ID will be before you call save(), because that value is calculated by your database, not by Django.

To query the database directly seems to be the only way.

But even then, you might have a case where you query for the next ID, and before inserting, another instance inserts a row, and you end up with a different ID, unless you wrap it all into a transaction.

Comment: Yeah, Postgres' nextval function will handle the atomicity for me, but as I looked at rolling my own wrapper to handle sqlite I realized that there isn't a comparable sqlite function.  Maybe the fact that dbs provide varying levels of operations on sequences is the reason my desired feature isn't implemented in Django.  Rats...